# Painting a Car, With small Air Compressor

Tags: paint

I want to paint my car but I only have a air compressor that is 8 gallons and produces 13.9 CFM. My air gun requires 12 CFM. Is it possible to use this air compressor and paint gun to paint my car?

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: Another concern: running a compressor for long periods - the thing is going to be going close to 100% duty cycle - will have a tendency to overheat the motor. Given the time-sensitive nature of painting (you need to keep a wet edge, and that stuff dries quite quickly), I'd be hesitant to do this with such a small compressor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compressor has a capacity of 13.9 CFM where the air gun requires only 12 CFM.

So YES, you should be able to successfully use this setup.

Comment: You may need to pause a few seconds at the end of each spray pass to let the pump catch up. Equipment does not always meet advertising claims.

Comment: Maybe for a bit, but I suspect the motor will overheat and shut down after awhile. My car has a 6500 RPM redline, but it won't be happy if I run it at that speed for an hour straight.

Comment: The compressor ran like a champ.